# find alghoritm for finding longes sequence of same elements with negative int

Tags: java

i have a task to find longest sequence of same value and this value, for such sequences

4 4 4 4 3 3 3 4 6 6 6 0

4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 6 6 6 0

4 4 333 333 4 3 -66 -66 -66 0

well, what I came up with doesn't work 100%...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Search for longest sequence: ");
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       int value;
       int prev = 0;
       int numOfLongestSequence = 0;
       int longestSequence = 1;
       int currentSequence = 0;

       while (s.hasNextInt() && (value = s.nextInt()) != 0) {
           if (prev == 0) {
               prev = value;
               continue;
           }
           if (value == prev) {
               currentSequence++;
           } else {
             if (currentSequence > longestSequence) {
                 longestSequence = currentSequence;
                 numOfLongestSequence = prev;
             }
             currentSequence = 1;
           }
           prev = value;
       }
        System.out.println("Longest sequence: " + longestSequence + " times " + numOfLongestSequence);
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work? How doesn't it work? What does it do that isn't what you expected?

Comment: In first case it misscounts 4s should be 4 times 4, guives 3 times 4. In last case does not see -66

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 mistakes which are giving wrong outputs for both inputs (1 and 3).

#### 1. Initialize `currentSequence` with 1

You should initialize `currentSequence` inside the statement `if (prev == 0)`. So, it also counts as the first element. (the cause for the counting 4s three).
The updated `if` statement will be:

```java
if (prev == 0) {
   prev = value;
   currentSequence = 1;
   continue;
}
```

#### 2. Also, check for the longest Sequence after the loop

The body of the loop does not execute when the input is `0`. So, it does not update `longestSequecne` for the last number (or sequence).
The same condition will be added after the loop.

```java
if (currentSequence > longestSequence) {
     longestSequence = currentSequence;
     numOfLongestSequence = prev;
}
```

So, the final code will look like:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Search for longest sequence: ");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int value;
    int prev = 0;
    int numOfLongestSequence = 0;
    int longestSequence = 1;
    int currentSequence = 0;

    while (s.hasNextInt() && (value = s.nextInt()) != 0) {

      if (prev == 0) {
        prev = value;
        // initialize the current sequence.
        currentSequence = 1;
        continue;
      }
      if (value == prev) {
        currentSequence++;
      } else {
        if (currentSequence > longestSequence) {
          longestSequence = currentSequence;
          numOfLongestSequence = prev;
        }
        currentSequence = 1;
      }
      prev = value;
    }

    // check for longest sequence
    if (currentSequence > longestSequence) {
      longestSequence = currentSequence;
      numOfLongestSequence = prev;
    }
    System.out.println("Longest sequence: " + longestSequence + " times " + numOfLongestSequence);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! indeed now it works. And thanks for step by step explanation.